# Wrong number of arguments Active Model Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I am using the 0.10 branch of AMS with a Rails 5.2 app and trying to bring up a first serializer. I'm getting the following error message:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)
```

with in my log:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `symbolize_keys' for #<Site:0x00007f80fdad2fc0>):
```

with:

```
module Api 
  module V1
    class SitesController < ApplicationController
      def show 
        @site = Site.find(params[:id])
        render json: @site, serializer: SiteSerializer
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and a serializer of:

```
class SiteSerializer < ActiveModelSerializers::Model
  attributes :id, :name
end
```

But I am confused as to why.

#### Edit #1

Rake routes:

```
       api_v1_sites GET  /api/v1/sites(.:format)                                                                  api/v1/sites#index
       api_v1_site GET  /api/v1/sites/:id(.:format)                                                              api/v1/sites#show
```

#### Edit #2

Looking at the log, I'm getting the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `symbolize_keys' for #<Site:0x00007f80fdad2fc0>):
```

Comment: What do you have in routes?

Comment: What does `render json: SiteSerializer.new(@site)` do?

Comment: swap your routes in order that first it should shave `api_v1_sites GET  /api/v1/sites(.:format) ` and then `api_v1_site GET  /api/v1/sites/:id(.:format) ` this routes.

Answer (score 0):

```
module Api 
  module V1
    class SitesController < ApplicationController
      def show 
        @site = Site.find(params[:id]).name
        render json: @site, serializer: SiteSerializer
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Let me know if this works?